# spark insert overwrite test

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I new to pyspark and would like to play with Insert Overwrite.

I have created a *test_overwrite* table with many records. 
Then I created an empty *test_overwrite_3* table from *test_overwrite* and put some data in it.
*(I made sure the structure is the same.)*

> insert overwrite test_overwrite_3 select * from test_overwrite limit 3

I would expect that after executing the code above my *test_overwrite_3* table with some dummy data would be deleted and it should have 3 records from my *test_overwrite* table.

Instead I got an error message like this:

> *Error in SQL statement: ParseException:  no viable alternative at input 'insert overwrite test_overwrite_3'(line 1, pos 17)
>   == SQL == insert overwrite test_overwrite_3
>   -----------------^^^ select * from test_overwrite*

Can anyone help what went wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

*`no viable alternative at input 'insert overwrite test_overwrite_3`*

a parse error, not a type error. [see this](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/hive/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/hive/InsertSuite.scala)

I could see table keyword is missing in your statement.

Example is :

```
sql(
      """
        |INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE table_with_partition
        |partition (p1='a',p2='b',p3='c',p4='c',p5='4')
        |SELECT 'blarr' FROM tmp_table
      """.stripMargin)
```